# CNN never overfit even with small dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm using a CNN to classify image on a small and inbalance dataset.
3500 images, 16 classes. I do:

- Data augmentation with keras augmenteur
- class weighting

I use the following model.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(24,kernel_size=3,padding='same',activation='relu',
        input_shape=(n,n,1)))
model.add(MaxPool2D())
model.add(Conv2D(48,kernel_size=3,padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D())
model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3,padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(96,kernel_size=3,padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Validation accuracy or validation loss are not good metrics for me to check overfiting since my data set is very unbalance. i'm using recall and F1 as metrics to see if my model perform well on the validation.

When i run model, validation recall is stuck (**it's never decrease**) while train accuracy keep improving.

**Is it the right thing to stop training model when recall stop increasing after X epoch?** Even if my training set accuracy is still growing?

Second question: when I train my model with no data augmentation, my model reach 99% accuracy on training set, while validation recall never decrease? It's look like my model can't overfit... What should I do in this situation?

Comment: can you upload your code of 'history' part?
if you don't want stop the training after X epochs, you can use 'callback_earlystopping', so the model could automatically select the best CNN.

Comment: i'm using code from here to compute metrics: https://medium.com/@thongonary/how-to-compute-f1-score-for-each-epoch-in-keras-a1acd17715a2. I know i can early stop and save best model but I dont know when to stop model :/. for for help

Comment: I think this question would fit best on https://stats.stackexchange.com/.
As a brief answer I would say that it's not a good idea to do early stopping on the recall: it's not a continuous metric like the loss. 
I am also surprised that you mention recall in a multi-class problem. What is recall exactly in this case? Is it the recall of one class?
Finally I don't understand why you want your recall to decrease.